# Django JSONField filtering Queryset

Tags: python, django, postgresql

For project I'm using Python 3.6.3, Django 2.0 and Postgre 9.4.
In my class Ticket, a have JSONField passenger

```
    passenger = JSONField(blank=True)
```

and my passenger JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "email": null, 
    "mobile": "21312", 
    "passport": "2141241", 
    "sms_sent": false, 
    "full_name": "something"
},
{
    "email": null, 
    "mobile": null, 
    "passport": "1231231", 
    "sms_sent": false, 
    "full_name": "Irfan"
},
{
    "email": null, 
    "mobile": null, 
    "passport": "1231231", 
    "sms_sent": true, 
    "full_name": "Irfan"
}
```

Now I have django command where I want to filter tickets that have mobile that is not null or None, and sms_sent is False.

```
    tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(
        date=tomorrow, trip__bus_company=bus_company,
        passenger__sms_sent=False
    ).not_cancelled()
```

Now passenger__sms_sent=False filter is working, and is giving my only Tickets with sms_sent=False. But passenger__mobile filter is not working.
I tried everyone of this:

```
    tickets = tickets.exclude(passenger__mobile=None)
    tickets = tickets.exclude(passenger__mobile=None).exclude(passenger__mobile='')
    tickets = tickets.exclude(passenger__mobile__isnull=True)
    tickets = tickets.exclude(passenger__exact={'mobile': None})
    tickets = tickets.exclude(passenger__mobile__isnull=True).exclude(passenger__mobile='')
    tickets = tickets.exclude(passenger__mobile__isnull=False).exclude(passenger__mobile='')
    tickets = tickets.exclude(Q(passenger__mobile__isnull=True) | Q(passenger__mobile=''))
```

and also puting passenger__mobile in first filter, but I can not filter out(exclude) tickets where passenger__mobile is null, I either get all tickets, or empty queryset.

Now I can do this:

```
for ticket in tickets:
            if ticket.passenger['mobile'] is not None:
                print(ticket.passenger['mobile'])
```

but that is not what I'm looking for. I want to use filter or exclude to get those tickets. What I'm I doing wrong?
P.S. not_cancelled() is my manager and it does not have anything to do with passenger field.

Comment: Are you sure there are records where there are null values in the database? `blank=True` will allow empty values in the form, but I believe you need `null = True` as well to allow nulls through django.

Comment: @Alan The thing is that my model was alredy blank=True, null=True, and in this case there is no differece, It still didn't work, so I changed it to only blank=True, so that it won't allow null and None. And in db it is "mobile": null

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25718 (see the last, closing comment) the following should work     `model.objects.filter(field__key=None)`  (But obviously **you should use the Django version with the fix**).

The django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield

warn that

> Since any string could be a key in a JSON object, any lookup other
>   than those listed below will be interpreted as a key lookup. No errors
>   are raised. Be extra careful for typing mistakes, and always check
>   your queries work as you intend.

and here they are https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#containment-and-key-operations

Comment: The thing is if I understand you, filter(passenger__mobile=None) would work, but in my case it doesn't. It gives me both tickets(third one is alredy filtered out by sms_sent=True). It gives me ticket where "mobile": null, and "mobile": '"21312".

Comment: Ok so in Django 2.1 this is going to be possible, but right now, I can manage with if ticket.passenger['mobile'] is not None: